# Translating the option labels of Dropdown, Checkboxes or Multi-select fields

Tags: localization

Is it possible to have the labels for any of these fields be translatable in templates? I don't mean make the whole field translatable - the same option values would be shared between locales, I would just like the output the label in the correct language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [translate (or t)](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#translate-or-t) filter:

```
{{label|t}}
```

See [how to translate static text in templates](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/static-translations)

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly. I didn't think it would work unless it was an actual string like {{ "Something"|t }}.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [LJ Dynamic Fields](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-dynamicfields/) plugin, you can also generate drop-down, checkbox, multi-select, and radio button labels/values dynamically from a another channel. If the lookup channel data is localized then the labels will be also. I implemented this for a localized drop-down country list. Works great! and client can control the entries. Powerful plugin.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('countries').limit(null).order('countryName') %}
  { "value":"{{ entry.countryCode }}" , "label":"{{ entry.countryName }}"}
  {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this is an excellent idea